# Multiple loss functions for multiple inputs in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My network has 2 inputs, one 3D grayscale volume and one 2D colour image. At the end I have one 2D output, same shape as the input image.

My problem : I want to combine 2 loss functions, one for each input branch of the network. One loss function should compare the prediction of the network to a 2D grayscale groundtruth, the other to the 2D colour input. These groundtruths are stored in separate files.

I do not understand how y_true works and how I can tell it to look at my groundtruth files. I think my problem is mostly one of syntax, and after looking at other posts on SO I'm just more confused.

Here's the code I have come up with. It doesn't work of course, but it should give an idea of what I'm aiming for.

```
def custom_loss(groundtruth_grayscale, groundtruth_colour):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        loss_grayscale = ssim(y_pred, groundtruth_grayscale)
        loss_colour = ssim(y_pred, groundtruth_colour)
        ssim_loss = loss_grayscale + loss_colour

        l1_loss_grayscale = l1(y_pred, groundtruth_grayscale)
        l1_loss_colour = l1(y_pred, groundtruth_colour)
        l1_loss = l1_loss_grayscale + l1_loss_colour

        return ssim_loss + l1_loss
    return loss

# images_groundtruth_grayscale is a variable containing all groundtruth_grayscale images
model_combined.optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.002).minimize(custom_loss(images_groundtruth_grayscale, images_groundtruth_colour), var_list = model_combined.trainable_variables)
```

If it helps, the model's summary :

```
model_combined.summary()
Model: "model_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, None, None,  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)                 (None, None, None, 1 9728        input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_2 (InputLayer)            [(None, None, None,  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNorma (None, None, None, 1 512         conv2d[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d (Conv3D)                 (None, None, None, N 16128       input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, None, None, 6 204864      batch_normalization[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (BatchNor (None, None, None, N 512         conv3d[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (BatchNor (None, None, None, 6 256         conv2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_1 (Conv3D)               (None, None, None, N 1024064     batch_normalization_4[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)               (None, None, None, 3 18464       batch_normalization_1[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_5 (BatchNor (None, None, None, N 256         conv3d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (BatchNor (None, None, None, 3 128         conv2d_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_2 (Conv3D)               (None, None, None, N 55328       batch_normalization_5[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)               (None, None, None, 1 4624        batch_normalization_2[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_6 (BatchNor (None, None, None, N 128         conv3d_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (BatchNor (None, None, None, 1 64          conv2d_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_3 (Conv3D)               (None, None, None, N 13840       batch_normalization_6[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_ExpandDims (TensorF [(None, None, None,  0           batch_normalization_3[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_7 (BatchNor (None, None, None, N 64          conv3d_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_add (TensorFlowOpLa [(None, None, None,  0           tf_op_layer_ExpandDims[0][0]     
                                                                 batch_normalization_7[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_4 (Conv3D)               (None, None, None, N 272         tf_op_layer_add[0][0]            
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,349,232
Trainable params: 1,348,272
Non-trainable params: 960
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: So where exactly does it go wrong?

Comment: Have you had a look at this? Seems like a pretty comprehensive tutorial on the subject: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/06/04/keras-multiple-outputs-and-multiple-losses/. In short though, you should implement *two* loss functions, one for each branch, then when you compile the model you need to tell Keras how to weight them

Comment: @BlueRine Right at the compilation of the model, `TypeError: loss() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y_true' and 'y_pred'`

Comment: @Karl But isn't that only valid when you have multiple outputs ? Or can you compile a model with multiple loss functions regardless of how many outputs it has ?

Comment: Ok, well here is where I get confused, because it sounds like your model has multiple *outputs*: one grayscale and one colour. Are `groundtruth_grayscale` and `groundtruth_colour` always fixed or do they vary per image? Because as it is written at the moment you will be training your model to only recognise one image. I presume though that the error you are getting is because what you are passing to `minimize` is only `y_pred` because your loss function doesn't actually use `y_true`

Comment: Just to be clear. Any optimization problem can *never* really have more than *1* objective (loss) function. Otherwise you would need a Pareto optimal point, which is not what you do with neural networks. You can however, weigh two (or more) criteria against each other and combine them into *one* loss function. This is actually commonly done in practice. (A weighted sum is a common example)

Comment: @Karl There is only one out 2D, colour output that is meant to be the fusion of the 3D grayscale volume and the 2D colour image. The groundtruths vary for each image. I have no use for y_true because I already have my groundtruths. Or am I missing a bit of syntax here where I can "set" y_true ?

Comment: @BlueRineS Interesting. What I have now is 1 loss function that sums up several criteria, right ? The problem then is how to make it so the loss functions takes into account the groundtruth I want. I wish I could upvote you 2, I'm really thankful for the help

Comment: I think you misunderstand how the nested function above works. You need to have your ground truths in `y_true`. That is what `y_true` is for. Putting something in `custom_loss(groundtruth_grayscale, groundtruth_colour` is only useful as a way of getting intitial (unchanging) information into the loss function without needing to pass it within the function itself, since the function must have the signature `y_pred, y_true`

Comment: Ok, but if I use `def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred)` instead, how can I get my colour and grayscale groundtruths "inside" y_true ? In other words, how do I get my loss function to compare the output to 2 separate groundtruths and balance the two comparisons ? Or do I absolutely have to have a single groundtruth at the end ?

Comment: I found the following tensorflow code to achieve my aim, do you know if there's a way to get something similar with only Keras, or at least TF 2.0 ? Basically, the code takes the inputs (placeholders) and builds the loss function on them.
`images_oth   = tf.placeholder(...)

images_mri   = tf.placeholder(...)

mri_loss = ssim(fused_image,images_mri)

oth_loss = ssim(fused_image,images_oth)

ssim_loss = (mri_loss + oth_loss)

model = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(total_loss)`

Comment: Create and compile a keras model (https://keras.io/models/model/) and call `model.fit(x=input_data, y=y_true, ...)`. This can work if you combine the grayscale and colour inputs input into a single multi-dimensional array, then split them apart inside the loss function. Otherwise (and possibly more sensible although more complicated) you'll have to create a network with two heads and create two separate losses, one for each head (as referred to in the link in my first comment)